# Probability of On-Time arrival - Tree diagram

Tags: probability, decision-trees

I need to determine the branches of a tree diagram for the following problem. John's car is in the garage and he has to take a bus to get to school. He needs to make all three connections on time to get to his class. If the chance of making the first connection on time is 80%, the second 80%, and the third 70%, what is the chance that john will make an on-time arrival?
Would you branch it out starting with 8/10  of a good first connection and 2/10 of a missed connection then only branch down the good connection side? 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Yes.  You would only need to keep track of the one path through the tree (the one where all connections are made).

Comment: Thank you!! So from the end of the branch (The final bus), would you take each fraction and multiply to come up with his probability of arriving on time? Meaning 8/10 x 8/10 x 7/10 = 56/125 (or .448 or 44.8%) chance of an on-time arrival. I'm not sure that i'm seeing this correctly. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If you have a tree diagram in which you have such 'fail conditions', you do not need to continue past a fail condition. So your first split is 8/10 and 2/10, and the 8/10 branch then splits again but the 2/10 branch does not, and so on.

Comment: Thank you!! So from the end of the branch (The final bus), would you take each fraction and multiply to come up with his probability of arriving on time? I'm not seeing what to do for some reason. Thank you again!

Comment: Meaning 8/10 x 8/10 x 7/10 = 56/125 (or .448 or 44.8%) chance of an on-time arrival

Comment: Just like any tree diagram, the probability of a branch is the probability of the branch leading to it times the probability of going down that branch of the tree. So, yes, the final probability of being on-time is the product of the probabilities of making each connection.

Comment: SamBC, Thank you so very much!!